# Spring data jpa/hibernate: updates after save() method are not visible in @Query-result set

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have method "process", that gets the list of data from some generator . Every data has it's own state (field stringValue) and some function id. The list can contains the data with common function id. The method "process" is called from other class, so the transaction is opened directly:

```
@Transactional
private void process(List<Data> data) {
    for (Data data : data) {
        saveAndGenerateEvent(data);
    }
}
```

After getting list of unprocessed data, there is the iterationg through it. In every step the event is generated and then data is saved.

```
private void saveAndGenerateEvent(Data data) {
    DataState newState = DataState.getByName(data.getStringValue()).orElse(null);
    DataState lastState = dataRepository.getLastData(data.getFunctionId(), Attribute.STATE.getId()).map(Data::getStringValue)
            .flatMap(DataState::getByName).orElse(null);
    if (newState != lastState) {
        // ... generate Event
    }
    dataRepository.save(data);
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {
        @Query(value = "SELECT d.* FROM data d WHERE d.function_id = ?1 AND d.attribute_id = ?2 AND NOT d.deleted " +
               "ORDER BY d.id DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
        Optional<Data> findLast(Long functionId, Integer attributeId);
    }
```

The problem - if there is several data for one function, the saving data at the end of the saveAndGenerateEvent is not visible in the second iteration of saveAndGenerateEvent in dataRepository.getLastData - it returns the last data for function that was before process-method. And the new created data is not visible. I try to use not native query - JPQL and Data JPA sequence, but result is same. I try to use saveAndFlush method of JpaRepository instead of save-method of CrudRepository, but the result is the same. What is the cause of this "lost update" after first iterations and how I can get an actual last data value in any iteration?

Comment: What database are you using? Just checked on postgres:14, spring boot 2.4.0 and everything works just fine. Could you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I think, the problem is the native query as it will bypass the current session and retrieve from DB which will not give the data back (as it is not persisted yet), May I know why are you using native query? I think you may use the JPQL instead.